# Clean and Visually-Appealing jQuery/JavaScript Graphing API

Tags: jquery, css, api, graph, graphing

I've been doing some research into various graphing APIs for use in a social media dashboard that I'm building, and I'm having trouble finding one that is both highly configurable and "clean" looking. I'd really rather use an API and build the dashboards myself instead of using a service because we'll have some of our own integrations - I don't want to be limited to what is offered in a dashboard package.

The graphs I'm looking to create would ideally look like some of the following. Flat, clean, and 'WP8-Metro' styled. **Anyone have any ideas?**

---

**Microsoft Component Art**

[image]

[image]

---

**Google Analytics**

[image]

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to use a true API and not a graph/chart by configuration the [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) is the winner.  If you want to use configuration bassed libs then [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) and [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) are good choices.

Comment: I've looked into d3.js. It looks very promising, but very daunting. In your experience, is it fairly easy to control and learn?

Comment: A lot of it is *roll-your-own*.  If you are confortable in javascript then after looking at enough examples and messing with it yourself, you should find it easy enough to learn.

Comment: I think I'll try and tackle d3. I always end up back at the site, so I think I'm done convincing myself that it's the best option. Thanks, Mr. Berry.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have good luck with [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/).

Answer (score 1):

d3.js is great, but the learning curve with Highcharts is a lot easier (and it's very robust).

http://www.highcharts.com/